# VBA Object required error depending on code arrangement

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

```
r = mainWS.Cells(count, 1).Value
paths = mainWS.Cells(i, 2).Value
pathd = mainWS.Cells(i, 6).Value

.....

If (r = "H") Then

    Application.Workbooks.Open (pathd & "\" & filed)
    Set dWB = Application.Workbooks(filed)
    Set tabD_WB = dWB.Sheets(tabd & "")

    Application.Workbooks.Open (paths & "\" & files)
    Set sWB = Application.Workbooks(files)
    Set tabS_WB = sWB.Sheets(tabs & "")

End If

Set uRange = tabD_WB.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(5, tabD_WB.UsedRange.Columns.count))
```

So, if I put the last line starting with Set uRange **inside the IF block** the exercise works perfectly. If I place it immediately afterwards/outside, it doesn't. Can you help me understand why?

The error I get (if it's outside) is `Object required`. Is this some mistake of Excel inner workings?

I'm puzzled. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I forgot to mention that r is indeed equal to "H" (in the first step of a for), so that's what puzzles me. In the second step, Set uRange = tabD_WB.Range....... should be based on the files and sheets "set" during the first step, and so on

Answer (score 3):

Why would you expect it to work when `tabD_WB` is referred to outside of the `IF` statement?

Unless you have more code that you're not showing us, you only set `tabD_WB` inside the `IF` statement, meaning the object is empty if `r <> "H"`, and you can't access the range of an empty object.

Comment: I forgot to mention that r is indeed equal to "H" (in the first step of a for), so that's what puzzles me. In the second step, Set uRange = tabD_WB.Range....... should be based on the files and sheets "set" for the first step, and so on

Comment: @Sam - this question is impossible to answer.  You haven't shown all the code, including variable declarations, we don't know if you're using `Option Explicit` or not, if `paths`, `files` and `tabs` contain valid values, etc.  Have you put break points in your code and stepped through it to make SURE that your `IF` statement is being executed?

Answer (score 1):

You can write your code

```
Application.Workbooks.Open (pathd & "\" & filed)
Set dWB = Application.Workbooks(filed)
Set tabD_WB = dWB.Sheets(tabd & "")
```

as

```
Set dWB = Application.Workbooks.Open(pathd & "\" & filed)
Set tabD_WB = dWB.Sheets(tabd)
```

Now regarding your error, you have not fully qualified your Cells() object. Try this

```
With tabD_WB
    Set uRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(5, .UsedRange.Columns.Count))
End With
```

I hope you have declared `uRange` as a `Range` somewhere in your code? Also if the IF condition is not true then there will be no workbooks object?